# postfix mta header "received by" server hostname for virtual domain

Tags: postfix

I have `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` all set-up for virtual domains with their own IPs for outgoing mail - they work.

However when postfix's `sendmail` adds an email to the queue, apparently it still passes the email through the host domain and adds a header to the email !

`Received: by hostname.blah`

Before passing it onto the proper virtual hostname and IP for mailing out

(note the Return-Path and sender IP is all correct in the email)

Why is postfix so stupid and passes the email through the host server despite the sender transport map?

Do I have to find another MTA ?

Is there maybe another option I can use with its `sendmail` mta  (I'm already using `-f` )

Another way of asking this is

`Can postfix's sendmail change "received: by" based on sender envelope ?`

or

`Can I tell postfix's sendmail where the message is coming from on the command line?`

It occurs to me if postfix listens on port 25 locally I might be able to initiate from the proper virtual host IP and it might figure this out. But that is overly complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some clarification:*

In case above, postfix is just *a messenger*. The source of the email was program who invoking postfix [sendmail](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html) binary. **One of responsibility of an email messenger was stamping every email with `Received:` header every time it received email**. It documented in [RFC 5231 Section "Received Lines in Gatewaying"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.7.2).

Now, when postfix sendmail binary adds an email to postfix queue, it put the email in maildrop binary **without `Received` header**. The one who put `Received` header was [pickup](http://www.postfix.org/pickup.8.html) daemon. When adding `Received` header, basically it tells us, "Hi, I have **received** email from sendmail binary userid xxx."

Your `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` will be invoked when in routing stage. Postfix won't evaluate it when receiving stage.

---

> Now the main question: **Can we disable this behavior?**

You can always manipulated postfix header using [`header_checks`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) feature. Taken the idea from this post: [Remove sensitive information from email headers with postfix](https://major.io/2013/04/14/remove-sensitive-information-from-email-headers-with-postfix/), you can use this pcre line to remove the unwated header.

```
/^Received: by hostname.blah.*from userid/ IGNORE
```

Comment: I already tried `header_checks` to replace that line - it either is unwilling or unable to modify that particular header. It may be added out of sequence. Pretty sure I have to replace postfix with exim to get what I want or maybe a more simple MTA - I'm not arguing postfix shouldn't add that header, I'm saying it is pretty stupid to have advanced sender maps without considering how mail is put into the queue in the first place.

Comment: update: your answer made me go back and try some more aggressive regex - and it worked - but instead of removing the line which breaks RFC rules, I replaced it with the proper hostname based on the userid (which I hope I never accidentally change) - thanks for the encouragement to try again